# how to communicate between a root React component and the rest of the app using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component  rendered on the root of my app that handles alerts.
I want to be able to pass different messages to that component from anywhere in my app and get the action that was selected by the user (Accept or Decline for example).
Since that component is not a child of the other components, I can't pass a callback to it as a prop.
**I don't want to "instance" that component on every component that needs to render it mainly because of markup organization.**
What is a good pattern to achieve this? Should I pass the actions that need to be dispatched from the Alert component in the invoking action itself?

Comment: Do you use redux in your project?

Comment: not certain I understand your question. Presumably your redux store contains the info to pass to your alert, then anywhere else in your app you can dispatch data to your store which will render your alert. is this insufficient in some way?

Comment: @azium Communicating from any component to the alert component seems doable indeed. But when the user selects an option from that alert, how can I send back that response to the component that needs to perform the following action?

Comment: by putting that data in your redux store. Someone clicks "open alert" then you dispatch your alert action sending any information you need. then the user clicks on a button in the alert putting stuff back into the store so the other component can access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Redux`. You just need to use a function `mapStateToProps` which returns an object and a helper function [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to conenect the store with your components. Then the `components` will receive the state as its own props when the state in Redux store has been changed. i.e. You acted an action and reducers returned (changed) the new values in the store, the components which have been **connected** will be rendered again since it (thinks itself) received new props.

For example, your **Redux store** (singleton) is

```
{
  alerts: [{
            id: 1001,
            message: "Hello",
            userAct: "Accepted",
            custType: "fromCompA",
            }, 
          {
            id: 1002,
            message: "World",
            userAct: "Declined"
            custType: "fromCompB",
            cb: function(){}
          }],
  others: {},
}
```

**mapStateToProps**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    alerts: state.alerts || []
  }
}
```

**connect**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  addAlert,
})(YourComponent)
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to do the different actions according to which component invoked it, you can add a `custom type` <s>or a callback</s> in your store's object.

Then your can use an action creator with a custom type like this (You can put custType into your param object, all depends on your design.)

```
const addAlert = (paramIsObjContainsCustType, param2, custType) => (
  { 
    type: "YOUR_ACTION_TYPE",
    payload: {
      message: param2,
      custType,
  }
)
```

And your component can get an alert object and **object.custType** (in the example). Then you can do stuff according to the value of it.

By @azium 's comments below, the callback way may miss some features of Redux like time travel. Therefore, to leave a metadata like `custType` in the store and react according to it should be a better way to do what you want.

And keep functions in the store might also cause some issues when we want to serialize the store. functions may be `null` when you do the serialization.

Comment: But how do I make a generic component like <Alerts> to dispatch different actions depending on who invoked it? Or execute a callback passed by the invoker?  
Remember the <Alerts> component is not a child of the component that invokes it.

Comment: @aiman You can add a type or a callback function to your **alerts** in the store. You can check my Redux store example again.

Comment: I think putting a callback function in the store is a questionable approach. I think it would simply be wiser to store some metadata about the caller of the initial component (id, action type) and have a generic callback dispatch the next action / do any behavioural stuff

Comment: @azium I think putting a simple callback should be fine according to [What Shouldn’t Go in State?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state) Otherwise, leave a custom type as I mentioned and do things in Reducers (change other values to make other components to react) according to the actions or other places.

Comment: @AndreLee  Yeah it's probably fine, but I think you lose some features of redux like time travel / undo/redo because context gets lost

Comment: @azium you are right, the undo/redo feature should be a concern of it. I will revise my answer and including your opinion. thank!

Comment: @AndreLee ok seems reasonable. At what point of the lifecyle of the component should I handle that custType? componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: @airman I'm not sure what you are going to do according to the custType . But yes, at least you can do that in componentWillReceiveProps. (You even can do stuff in render() phase if you only want to change some colors of it.) BTW, do you have <Alert /> in your <Alerts />? If yes, you can also bypass and use the custType in it. (all depends on your design.)